# Adapter getView() with Listener inside

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-arrayadapter, adapter

I created a GridView and an Adapter for that. In the getView() method, I made this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    viewHolder = new RecordHolder();
    final Sticker sticker = data.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        viewHolder.count = sticker.getAmount();
        viewHolder.textViewNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNumber);
        viewHolder.textViewQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantity);
        viewHolder.iv_logo_card = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_logo_card);
        viewHolder.buttonAdd = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        viewHolder.buttonRemove = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonRemove);
        viewHolder.textViewQuantity.setText(sticker.getAmount().toString());
        paintQuantity(viewHolder.count, viewHolder, context);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (RecordHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (viewHolder.count != 99) {
                viewHolder.count++;
            }
            sticker.setAmount(viewHolder.count);
            StickerBusinessService.saveSticker(sticker);
            viewHolder.textViewQuantity.setText(sticker.getAmount().toString());
            paintQuantity(viewHolder.count, viewHolder, context);
        }
    });
```

It's correct to write the .setOnClickListener inside this method? Exists a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the click listener once for each view, rather than every time getView() is called. You should also probably consider whether you want a button in a GridView, as generally users would just click the whole View to perform an action.

```
if (convertView == null) {
    // add listener here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !
But it's not working properly... Now, it's adding/subtracting the count, but its not adding/subtracting for each item, it's adding/subtracting for all itens. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Not too sure what you mean by adding/subtracting for all items, but your viewHolder.count needs to be updated everytime getView is called (assuming it is part of your model)

Comment: Thanks for all answers! Now it's working correctly! 
I just put the following code when the row == 0:
    if (row == null) {
            holder = new RecordHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        }

Answer (score 0):

try this tutorial
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/
just replace the list view with the grid view hope this will help you